# Google Cloud Dataflow data sampling issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I use Dataflow prime and all the defaults. As my pipeline fails, I expect to see samples, as exception-based sampling is enabled by default ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/data-sampling?_gl=1*e73hud*_ga*MTc3MTU1NzE3MS4xNjc5NzYyNDUy*_ga_WH2QY8WWF5*MTcxMTYzMTczNi4yNjkuMS4xNzExNjQ0MzQxLjAuMC4w&_ga=2.43145317.-1771557171.1679762452)).

I use "--temp_location=gs://bucket/beam/tmp". The Dataflow job reads and writes to "gs://bucket/“ with no problem.

However, I don't see samples and the UI suggests that I don't have permission. What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/data-sampling#permissions_error?

Comment: yeah, the job can read and write to the bucket.

Comment: "Make sure the job and workers are in a healthy state." If a job ran into exception and failed, can I still see the samples?

Comment: Was the permission error gone?